# How can I add two different active classes to two different tabs on click(the way it looks on the image)

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I am trying to improve my JQuery/JavaScript Skills and I have been trying to make a tab navigation, with 3 tabs(This is obviously just to practice, since there are definitely more ways to use this technique) 
Screenshot of what I am trying to make: http://prntscr.com/n8l9jf

I am fairly new to JS, which is why I am asking this obviously. I know how to add an active class to one tab and change to that tab with data-target, but this is obviously a bit more advanced.

```
<div class="nav-item" id="nav-item1" data-target="#blog-con">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <h6>HOME</h6>
</div>
            <!-- Resume/CV Tab -->
<div class="nav-item" id="nav-item2" data-target="#cv-con">
    <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
    <h6>RESUME</h6>
</div>
            <!-- Web Tab -->
<div class="nav-item" id="nav-item3" data-target="#web-con">
     <i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i>
     <h6>WEB-DESIGN</h6>
</div>
```

```
$('.nav-item').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
    $('.tab').not($target).hide();
    $target.show();
});
```

```html
This is the code I used to create the screenshot
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="tab active" id="business" data-target="#busi-con">
         <p>information.html</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab inactive" id="front.html" data-target="#front-con">
          <p>front.html</p>
     </div>
     <div class="tab inactive" id="main.css" data-target="#main-con">
          <p>main.css</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

```css
the css for the example
.tab{
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    background-color: #3a3837;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;

}
.active{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    z-index: 999;
}
.active2{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    z-index: 950;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.active3{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    z-index: 900;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

In Short Form: What I am trying to achieve is making the inactive tabs appear darker. so inactive with 0.8 opacity and inactive2 with 0.6. And the plan is also to make the decision of what has inactive and what has inactive2 class added fixed, in a way that is always left to right. 
 
I hope this isn't written to complicated.
I am really thankful to anybody that helps me out with this. I am only a student and obviously, I am still in the process of learning

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just `css` using `+` selector

```js
$('.nav-item').click(function() {
    $('.nav-item').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* default class style */
.nav-item{
  display : inline-block;
  background : #000;
  color : #fff;
}
.nav-item > h6{
  border-bottom : 5px solid #fff;
  padding : 10px;
  min-width : 100px;
  text-align : center;
  font-size : 20px;
  opacity : 0.4;
}

/* active class style */
.nav-item.active > h6{
  border-bottom : 5px solid red;
  opacity : 1;
}

/* next div of active */
.nav-item.active + div.nav-item > h6{
  border-bottom : 5px solid yellow;
  opacity : 0.6;
}

/* next next of active */
.nav-item.active + div.nav-item + div.nav-item > h6{
  border-bottom : 5px solid green;
  opacity : 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-item" id="nav-item1" data-target="#blog-con">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <h6>HOME</h6>
</div>
            <!-- Resume/CV Tab -->
<div class="nav-item" id="nav-item2" data-target="#cv-con">
    <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
    <h6>RESUME</h6>
</div>
            <!-- Web Tab -->
<div class="nav-item" id="nav-item3" data-target="#web-con">
     <i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i>
     <h6>WEB-DESIGN</h6>
</div>
```